# How can I retrieve the number of videos uploaded by a specific Youtube user?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

How can I retrieve the number of videos uploaded by a specific Youtube user? I have been searching for the answer, but can't seem to find it.

Using the information you get from this

> gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/uploads

I can see a limit of 50 videos. But I would like to get a total count. Would anyone know how I can get this?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the video count from here:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME_HERE/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=0
```

And then you can easily use javascript or whatever to pick out what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
<?php
$JSON = file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/YOUTUBE USERNAME/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=0");
$JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
$totalvideos = $JSON_Data->{'data'}->{'totalItems'};
?>
```