# Get Total Number of Uploads from YouTube User via JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, youtube, youtube-api

I have been trying to find the total number of uploads by a certain user and found the following thread.

[How can I retrieve the number of videos uploaded by a specific Youtube user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970501/how-can-i-retrieve-the-number-of-videos-uploaded-by-a-specific-youtube-user)

The answer to this problem works great and all when I hit the URL from a browser, but when I go in Obj-C to hit the following URL it returns NULL for me.

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/megangore/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=0

I'm using the following code, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm going nuts here.

```
NSString *URL = @"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/megangore/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=2";
NSLog(@"*******%@", URL);

dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
    @autoreleasepool{
        NSLog(@"******* PERFORMING STUFF *******");
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(processOrders:)withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
});
```

and that in turn calls

```
//GOES TO SERVER AND LOOKS AT WORK ORDERS
-(void)processOrders:(NSData *)responseData
{

NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1

                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

//AMOUNT OF WORK ORDERS
NSArray* Orders = [json objectForKey:@"body"]; //2
NSDictionary* nextOrder = [Orders objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* TotalNumber = [nextOrder objectForKey:@"totalItems"];
NSLog(@"**********************************%@", TotalNumber);
}
```

Also:

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) //1
```

---

HERE'S THE ANSWER

```
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1

                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

//AMOUNT OF WORK ORDERS
NSDictionary *returnedData = json[@"data"];
NSNumber *uploadCount = returnedData[@"totalItems"];
int value = [uploadCount intValue];
NSLog(@"loans: %i", value);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the output from the link provided

```
 {"apiVersion":"2.1","data":{"updated":"2013-10-08T17:44:29.337Z","totalItems":115,"startIndex":1,"itemsPerPage":0}}
```

There is no "body" key and there is no array. If total items in the upload count,

```
   NSDictionary *returnedData = json[@"data"];
   NSNumber *uploadCount = returnedData[@"totalItems"];
```

Comment: This works!!! Thank you! I just added a little typecasting to it to get the integer value. See above! :D

Comment: Good to hear, wasn't sure of the data type you needed. An upvote would also be appreciated